# Sort computed property on an ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

I have the following jsbin: http://jsbin.com/okoxim/4/edit

filteredContent is a computed property which is filtering my Controller's content. I want to know how to sort the computed property and any ways I can improve the code I have.

```
App.StudentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['name'],
  nameFilter: null,
  filteredContent: function(){
    if(!this.get('nameFilter')) return this.get('content');

    var nameRegEx = new RegExp(this.get('nameFilter'), 'i');
    return this.filter(function(item) {
      return item.get('name').search(nameRegEx) !== -1;
    });
  }.property('nameFilter', '@each.name')
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest way is to wrap the result in an `ArrayProxy` which sorts on the same `sortProperties` values. Something like,

```
filteredContent: function(){
  var result;

  if (!this.get('nameFilter')) {
    result = this.get('content');      
  } else {
    var nameRegEx = new RegExp(this.get('nameFilter'), 'i');
    result = this.filter(function(item) {
      return item.get('name').search(nameRegEx) !== -1;
    });
  }

  var sortedResult = Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(
    Ember.SortableMixin, 
    { content:result, sortProperties: this.sortProperties }
  );

  return sortedResult;
}.property('nameFilter', '@each.name')
```

Here's the updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/azosey/2).

Another way is to make `filteredContent` an explicit `ArrayProxy` and filter/sort on that.